# Pandas dataframe conditional validation with multiple column

Tags: python, pandas

How would I configure the validation logic below in pandas?

If the "EventType" field is filled with the value '1', '2', '3', '4', or '6', then the 'Category' field can not be filled with value '0'.

I configured this validation as below in excel but can not think of a way do this in pandas as I'm only starting to program in python.

**=IF(OR(EventType=1;EventType=2;EventType=3;EventType=4;EventType=6);IF(Category=0;1;0);0)**

1 = Fail
0 = Pass

Comment: See if you require and further clarification or any further help needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use nested [`np.where()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) as follows:

```
df['Fail/Pass'] = np.where(df['EventType'].isin([1, 2, 3, 4, 6]), np.where(df['Category'] == 0,  1, 0) , 0)
```

[`np.where()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) works like a if-then-else statement and acts similar to the Excel `=IF` statement.  Hence, you should be able to translate the Excel formula with ease.